# Registering intent filter to open email attachment from Gmail and native mail through my app

Tags: android

In my app I am generating custom files with my own extension.
I have to send these files as an email attachment, and receiver's side I have to open this attachment through my application.

For this I got a reference.

[Android: Registering Intent Filter to open email attachment with my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462816/android-registering-intent-filter-to-open-email-attachment-with-my-app)

This is working fine for Gmail attachments and not for native mail clients.
means I am able to open Gmail attachments but can't native mail attachments.

Can anyone suggest the way which will work for all email clients.

Regards,
Pradeep_ch.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone suggest the way which will work for all email clients.

There is no way that will work with all email clients. There is no requirement that an email client retain your file's extension in the `Uri` that it uses with `ACTION_VIEW`.